# Mathematica never seems to stop

Tags: equation-solving

***Find  $a$,$b$ if $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{2008}$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.***

---

**When I set  the `Range` to 10 000, Mathematica never seems to stop.**

**When I set the `Range` to 1000 000, there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.**

```
list1 = Range[10000];
f[{a_, b_}] := 1/a + 1/b;
Pick[Tuples[list1, 2], f[#] & /@ Tuples[list1, 2], 1/2008]
```

---

*Is there anyone who can solve this fuss?*
I have 16GB of RAM. I thought that is enough to find the answer below 10000

Comment: Have you tried evaluating `Reduce[1/a + 1/b == 2008 && a > 0 && b > 0, {a, b}, Integers]`?

Comment: @J.M., I just try your method , but only get `False`.

Comment: Are you sure your problem isn't $1/a + 1/b = 1/2008$? I've seen this sort of a problem being mentioned in that form somewhere recently... (and you can find all solutions to that problem with `Solve[1/a + 1/b == 1/2008 && 0 < a <= b, {a, b}, Integers]`.

Comment: @kirma which forum are you talking about? Can you provide me a link or something else?

Comment: "only get `False`" - indeed, and that's a sign to re-examine your equation to make sure you copied it correctly. Now, if you change `2008` to `1/2008`, tho...

Comment: @kirma Your method with `Solve` works. However, how can I solve this issue of my code?

Comment: @kile It was probably this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123923/find-all-ordered-pairs-a-b-such-that-1-a-1-b-3-2018-and-a-b-are-posi - nonetheless, largest number you can form with positive integers on $1/a + 1/b$ is $2$ when assigning $1$ to both $a$ and $b$...

Comment: @kirma Thank you for your link. Is there anything wrong  with my code? Why is Mathematica not stopping when execute my code?

Comment: `Table[If[1/a + 1/b == 1/2008, {a, b}, Nothing ], {a, 1, 10000}, {b, a,
     10000}] // DeleteCases[#, {}] & // AbsoluteTiming` evaluates  `{{{3012, 6024}}, {{4016, 4016}}}` in  155 seconds!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Great work!

Comment: @kile Sorry, Real Work interrupted me looking at this, thankfully others looked at it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works but is a terrible way of solving the problem:

```
list1 = Range[10000];
f[{a_, b_}] = 1/a + 1/b;
Select[Tuples[list1, 2], f[#] == 1/2008 &]

(*    {{3012, 6024}, {4016, 4016}, {6024, 3012}}    *)
```

Comment: How long does it take for your computer to find out the results? My computer runs for 5 mins and  still can't return a result even if I used your code.

Comment: @kile `Tuples` creates a big list, which can easily cause your machine to run out of RAM, which makes this drastically slower. 16 GB of RAM is not enough to do this comfortably. There's also experimental function called `SubsetCases` in v12.1 but it doesn't really scale well to such large sets.

Comment: @Roman How much RAM does it need? My PC just locks on it. Is there a way to solve it, in smaller pieces? I suppose it is an all (10000) or nothing question?

Comment: `Tuples[list1, 2] // ByteCount` gives `1600000208` which is 1.6 GB, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As I said this is a terrible way of solving your problem. Use `Solve` or iterate over the lists without storing them or ...

Comment: @Roman Interestingly I see my kernel growing essentially without a bound when I run that piece of code.

Comment: @kirma What is your `$Version` ?

Comment: @Roman how can I iterate without storing them? Can you show me?

Comment: @kile UlrichNeumann showed how to do it in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

This way seems to be pretty quick:

```
Solve[1/a + 1/b == 1/2008, b]
(*{{b -> (2008 a)/(a - 2008)}}*)

Reduce[b == (2008 a)/(a - 2008) && 0 < a < b && a ∈ Integers && b ∈ Integers]

(*(a == 2009 && b == 4034072) || (a == 2010 && 
   b == 2018040) || (a == 2012 && b == 1010024) || (a == 2016 && 
   b == 506016) || (a == 2024 && b == 254012) || (a == 2040 && 
   b == 128010) || (a == 2072 && b == 65009) || (a == 2259 && 
   b == 18072) || (a == 2510 && b == 10040) || (a == 3012 && 
   b == 6024)*)
```

Comment: Also `FindInstance[a*b == 2008 (a + b), {a, b}, Integers, 6]` if you just want 6 solutions for example.